How can I grab a substring of a string value in Postgres SQL, and replace another row with this substring?
I am working with the following table:
   id       fid                 ts             val
403307394   900     2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   Futures
403307394   901     2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   FSR3 SI 20220615 CS
403307394   4055    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   202209
403307394   4057    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   202209

What I am trying to achieve is to grab the row with fid = 901, i.e. FSR3 SI 20220615 CS (this is a string by the way), and I would like to grab just the YearMonth, i.e. 202206, and I would like to replace the rows with fid = 405 and 4057 with this date/
My desired table would look like:
  id       fid                 ts             val
403307394   900     2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   Futures
403307394   901     2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   FSR3 SI 202206 CS
403307394   4055    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   20220615
403307394   4057    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   20220615

I am not sure if the above is possible to achieve, but it seems like it may be!
Appreciate any help!
N.B. I have a long list of ids I would like to apply the solution to, so a generic solution would be ideal! :)

Do you want to write a select only or to update the table? Are you after a solution for exactly this data/this id or do you need a more generic solution for more data?

Update the table please if possible.

And a more generic solution! Thanks for asking, I'll add it to the question. As I have a long list of id's I'll need to apply it to

@user21641220 If the DATE is only one in VAL, you could you @YearMonth = SUBSTRING(val, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', val), 6). You must before declare @YearMonth as VARCHAR(6).
